# SQLAlchemy session within Huey periodic task

Tags: sqlalchemy, pyramid, python-huey

I'm integrating [Huey](http://huey.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) with a simple pyramid app. I'm not using a global SQLAlchemy session in the app (I'm making use of the latest alchemy scaffold). However, there seems to be no other straightforward way to provide a session to periodic tasks.

```
from huey import RedisHuey

huey = RedisHuey(password=os.environ.get('REDIS_PASSWORD', ''))
DBSession = scoped_session(sessionmaker())


@huey.periodic_task(crontab(minute='*/1'))
def notify_not_confirmed_assignments():
    # TODO: Use a non-global DB session
    assignments = DBSession.query(Assignment).filter_by(date=next_date).all()
```

Does Huey offer hooks to close the DB connection on task completion? What is the best way to provide a thread-safe connection to these tasks?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scoped_session` provides you with a [contextual/thread-local session](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/contextual.html#unitofwork-contextual) (i.e. it corresponds to an individual DB connection in each thread, and it's also possible to [configure a custom scope](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/contextual.html#using-custom-created-scopes) when you need a separate session per something which is not a thread.

So, basically, all you need to do is to have a properly-configured pseudo-global variable (similar to what you have now) and make sure you call DBSession.begin() at the start of the task and DBSession.commit() at the end - doing that manually is probably a chore but it can easily be abstracted into a context manager

```
def my_task():
    with magically_start_session() as session:
        session.query(...)
```

or into a decorator:

```
@huey.periodic_task(crontab(minute='*/1'))
@start_session
def notify_not_confirmed_assignments(session):
    # TODO: Use a non-global DB session
    assignments = session.query(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can build session object with a factory in the tasks:

```
factory = sessionmaker()
factory.configure(bind=engine)
session = factory()
```

No need to use scoped session, just initialize the engine and pass it to factory.